# Styling list-cell of javafx listview with custom style class

Tags: css, listview, javafx

I have a JavaFX ListView with an custom styleclass (selectlist). This should be styled different to all other ListViews in the application. 
How can I style it's cells? 
I have tried thisone in css file, but doesn't work:

```
.list-cell:even > .selectlist {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.list-cell:odd > .selectlist{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Would be nice if you could give me a hint...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `.selectlist > .list-cell:even {}`. You may also have to remove the `>`.

Comment: Thank you, .selectlist .list-cell:even {  -fx-background-color: white; }
did the trick.